# reference to UITextField not working?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created a controller class in which I have created a outlet to UITextfield. But The problem is that I am unable to get reference in the controller class, so unable to call any of textfield methods. The reference is returning null.
I have defined outlet (and connected them) properly to the text field in class but still not able to find the error.I am clean bowled !!

Comment: what exactly you are doing with the controller. are you creating controller object from some other controller and setting this textfield value or something like this?

Comment: which methods you are talking about and where you are printing textfield object?

Comment: Can you provide more info ? A little bit of code on how you are referencing your uitextfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You Adopted
 "UITextFieldDelegate" Protocol in your "ViewController.h"..?.

If Not You need to Add that protocol inside the "< >" of your "ViewController.h".

UITextFieldDelegate protocol contains various Method Declaration which called during the  Various Event(begin text Editing,ended text Editing,).

[For detail Information go Through this Link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Did you added this delegate into .h file of your ViewController? Which is required to used its methods?